# Cmake api compiling is different from what shown in the api documentation

Tags: python, c++, cmake, realsense

i've tried for over a week to compile this api https://github.com/IntelRealSense/RealSenseID (it's my frist time using Cmake) .
On the official documentation it is shown how to compile the api for python (because i must use python for the application requested) , but by following this guide (official documentation) https://github.com/IntelRealSense/RealSenseID/tree/master/samples/python, all i get is this, and i have no clue where to find "rsid.dll and rsid_py*.pyd" as said in the docs:
[image]

Cmake compiling doesn't shows any errors.

Probably it is a stupid question, but i really don't know what to do anymore and i'm going crazy.

Thank you :)

Comment: ty, yes i tried it but i don't get the needed files, all i get is: a empty Debug folder, reid_py.dir wich contains a Debug folder and a log file , and a x64 folder that contains log files.

Comment: Open the `.sln` instead, and look at the targets available to build.  Does it have an rsid_py target?  What happens when you build that target.  Did you invoke cmake with the correct options?  `cmake -DRSID_PY=ON -DRSID_PREVIEW=ON ..`

Comment: yes it has a rsid_py, and if i build it, the output says failed, `1>Done building project "rsid_py.vcxproj" -- FAILED.`. Yes i invoked cmake with the correct options. I also saw an issues on github of this guy https://github.com/IntelRealSense/RealSenseID/issues/114 , i followed it but got nothing

Comment: I now updated visual studio and the build logs has this errors: `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'RealSenseID/Logging.h': No such file or directory`. i don't know how i can import it